# React - importing todos but I don't see it in the file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm doing Redux tutorial. In that I found a code that I can't understand.

In MainReducer file it says `import todos from './TodoReducer'` but there's no todos in TodoReducer.js file but it's still working. todos seems to be a state name by the way. Why does this still work?

The whole source can be found in:
https://itnext.io/tutorial-simple-react-redux-app-cd559621ec00

```
MainReducer.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './TodoReducer'
import visibilityFilter from './FilterReducer'

export default combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
})
```

```
import { ADD_TODO, REMOVE_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO} from '../actions/actionsTypes'

const INITIAL_DATA = []

const TodoReducer = (state=INITIAL_DATA, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case ADD_TODO:
        return [
            ...state,{
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text,
                completed: false,
            }
        ]
        case TOGGLE_TODO:
        return state.map(todo =>
        (todo.id === action.id)
          ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
          : todo
         )
        case REMOVE_TODO:
        const numIndex = parseInt(action.id)
        return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== numIndex);
        default:
        return state
    }
}

export default TodoReducer
```

```
import {
  SHOW_ALL,
  SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER
} from "../actions/actionsTypes";

const visibilityFilter = (state = SHOW_ALL, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return action.filter;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default visibilityFilter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how [`defalut` exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export) work. Whatever is being called in the format

```
import whatever from './TodoReducer'
```

`whatever` will be assigned the `default` export from './TodoReducer'.
This is in contrast to [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports) when you call

```
export Something;
```

You must import it using the same name as

```
import { Something } from './TodoReducer'
```

note the curly braces here. 
For more information read `export` [documentation on MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 1):

todos is just a name that you are giving to call function which is TodoReducer, 
It is not the name that should be present in the function, it can be anything.

For you, path that you are providing should be proper.